Usdt recovery from address? 
I'm in need of serious help Here, I have transferred all my usdt to usdt contract address and it's literally all I have rn and it has screwed my life, please If anyone can help or give advice all appreciated and I will drop the information here, thanks for all
Transaction hash: 0xc2594d761619cded0c7854ce174e8a6922154237522dc9a7caf547e9f9a80960

please provide the address you sent your funds to

Transaction hash: 0xc2594d761619cded0c7854ce174e8a6922154237522dc9a7caf547e9f9a80960

The Usdt address:0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7

You did indeed transfer the assets to the USDT contract. Best thing to do is contact IFinex or BitFinex who operate that contract, provide the tx hash and they may be able to help. Good luck!

I did contact bitfinex and they just asked me to contact tether and tether told me it's not in thier appetite to help me, but i'll give ifinex a try, thank you though.
